# Write out bind/named log messages to a different file using rsyslog

Tags: bind, rsyslog

Right now, the contents of /etc/rsyslog.conf which control disposition of the named log messages looks like:

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;;kern.none     /var/log/messages
```

Putting the following in **front** of that section correctly writes out the "named" messages to /var/log/named/named.log.

```
# Write named/bind messages to their own log file
:programname, isequal, "named"                          /var/log/named/named.log
```

The problem is that those "named" messages are still being written out to the /var/log/messages file.  How would I modify the line that generates /var/log/messages to not write out "named" messages?

Note: This is rsyslog v5 as ships with RHEL/CentOS 6.

Addendum: The accepted answer from below is

```
# Write named/bind messages to their own log file, then discard (tilde)
:programname, isequal, "named"                          /var/log/named/named.log
:programname, isequal, "named"                          ~
```

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: CentOS 5/6 and RHEL 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using negation can be useful if you would like to do some generic
>   processing but exclude some specific events. You can use the discard
>   action in conjunction with that. A sample would be:
>
> *.* /var/log/allmsgs-including-informational.log
>
> :msg, contains, "informational"  ~
>
> *.* /var/log/allmsgs-but-informational.log
>
> Do not overlook the red tilde in line 2! In this sample, all messages
>   are written to the file allmsgs-including-informational.log. Then, all
>   messages containing the string "informational" are discarded. That
>   means the config file lines below the "discard line" (number 2 in our
>   sample) will not be applied to this message. Then, all remaining lines
>   will also be written to the file allmsgs-but-informational.log.

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html